# Loading time of Angular2 application on Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, angular, webview, frontend

I'm writing to enquire about loading time of my own angular2 application. Size of my app is not larger then 1,5MB (9MB with *.js.map files) and initial loading time on chrome browser is max 3-4 seconds.
There is a problem with android webview. The same app loading time on android webview is about 10-14seconds. 
I'm using standard webpack configuration. 
*Angular2 Universal* will help? (server-side rendering)
Maybe, anyone know reason and can explain me why loading time on webview is so long. Some tools, library which help me?

Answer (score 2):

I am also developing a Angular 2 app which will load up in the Android Webview.
I faced the same slow loading problem. Finally i found a solution

I changed my project into Android CLI project then

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

for building the project and it reduced my project size.

Comment: Yep,it's good idea. I uped your answer, but to use Ahead-Of-Time compilation you must follow a few rules from the beginning of project creation. In my case, I had to do total refactor my project :)

Comment: Any idea how can i call a android function in my angular app as when i am trying to call android function i am doing this `android_webview.android_function()` but `android_webview` is undefined for angular and this restricts me from doing ng build